# How to resize png files to fit itunes connect requirement?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm having a little trouble submitting an screen shot in .png format to iTunes Connect. I took a screenshot of the app from the iPhone, and it's 640 x 960 pixels. This works for the 3.5 inch section in iTunes Connect, but not for other sections such as the 4-inch, which requires 640 x 1096, and the iPad, 768 x 1024.

My question - can I just leave the other sections blank - i.e., just provide the screenshot for the 3.5 inch?   Does iTunes Connect handle the missing sections when displaying in the app store? It seems like it may have been doing that for previous iterations of this app (which I wasn't originally involved with)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im pretty sure when your app gets approved you are going to get alerts form itunes connect telling you that you need to submit all the screenshots (Especially the iphone ones), even the page dont let you save changes until you upload everything.

I strongly recommend you to upload screenshots for all devices, I insist, especially iphone, so you dont have any problems and you can have a clean publish.

Theres an online tool [LaunchKit](https://launchkit.io/) where you can generate screens for all devices at once.

Hope it helps.